# How can i mark text in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Please help me out with this code

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def click():

    t.insert(INSERT,"{}")
    t.mark_names()
    t.mark_set(INSERT,1.1)
    t.mark_gravity(INSERT,RIGHT)
b=Button(root,text="click",command=click)
b.pack()

t=Text(root)

t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So the insertion point will remain where it is. How can I make the insertion point to move along with the parenthesis assuming  I type and click that button again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the puzzle. I wasn't familiar with any of the mark functions. I think the t.mark_names is obsolete, but I left it in.

Classes are perfect for this. You might be able to do it with global variables as well, but that's not needed and I never use them. So I don't know how to do that.

I added `t.see("insert")` to see what's happening. You have to click the text field first in order to see it.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

class clicker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def click(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.index = float(str(1) + "." + str(self.count))
        self.correctfloat = format(self.index, ('.' + str(len(str(self.count))) + 'f'))
        t.see("insert")
        t.insert(INSERT,"{}")
        t.mark_names()
        t.mark_set(INSERT,self.correctfloat)
        t.mark_gravity(INSERT,RIGHT)

c = clicker()

b=Button(root,text="click",command=c.click)
b.pack()

t=Text(root)

t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```